# how to simplify conditional code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a student I am new to python, This is my first code, any one help me to simplify this code.

```
A=[5,"c","d"]
total=0

for item in A:
  
    if (item == 5):
        total= item
    if (item == "c"):
        total= total-1
        
    if (item == "d"):
        total= total*2
        print("total",total)
```

my requirement:

when the array loop is run, if the loop find the 'c' charactor it should reduce the previous value. incase there is a 'd' in loop, it should double the previous value. for me I am getting result as `8`. it fine. looking for clean and simple way to get the same as learning.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarizes the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Without knowing what the code is supposed to do this looks straight forward enough. You do, however, probably have a bug in where your `print` function is placed - I think you want it one or two levels dedented, so it either prints the current total or else prints the final total.

You can improve both performance and readability somewhat by using `elif` over `if` for the second and third conditional check, and you can use operators like `-=` and `*=` to shorten the code somewhat.

All in all:

```
arr = [5, "c", "d"]
total = 0

for item in arr:
    if (item == 5):
        total = item
    elif (item == "c"):
        total -= 1
    elif (item == "d"):
        total *= 2

print(total)
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where you don't know what the code is supposed to do. Such questions are off-topic for this site, and the existence of your answer makes it impossible to fix the question because that would create a mess.